# Fetch with react native

Tags: react-native, fetch-api

I am using fetch in React Native in order to make a call to my API, however, it only works 75% of the time.
When my request doesn't work I get this :

> TypeError: Network request failed

or

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0

```
fetch('http://localhost/vision.php', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
          'Accept': 'application.json',
          'Content-Type': 'application.json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
          key: 'Mon paramètre'
      })
    })
    .then((data) => data.json())
    .then((dataJson) => {
        console.log(dataJson.message);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Someone can explain that?

Comment: If you put "if (dataJson !== null) {..." after this line: ".then((dataJson) => {", it´s still happens?

Answer (score 0):

When you get `TypeError: Network request failed`, it means that, well, the network request failed. It *could* mean the API / server you're trying to connect to is down / not listening for connections anymore.

Regarding `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`, that's what you get when trying to parse non-JSON as JSON. Typically here it's likely your API / server failing to fulfill your request and, instead of JSON, serving you an HTML error page.

You might want to check if `data.ok` is `true` before trying to parse the JSON response (`data.json()`).

Comment: Ok thanks but it's API google with google server so I don't thinks it is down but ok for JSON

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect that it *could* be it.